# What is the probability that two nodes are connected in a random graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, graph-connectivity

I have just started with the theory of random graphs. I have come across the following expression of the probability that two nodes $i$ and $j$ are connected where $k_i$ and $k_j$ are the respective node degrees and $m$ is the number of edges in the graph, according to Erdos and Renyi:

$$p_{ij}=\frac{k_ik_j}{2m-1}$$

According to my understanding, the probability should be the number of possible connections between $i$ and $j$ divided by the total number of possible connections in the graph. In that sense the numerator of the formula is obvious. Can any of you explain me the denominator or the formula as a whole?

I was consulting [this](http://www.leonidzhukov.net/hse/2015/networks/lectures/lecture3.pdf) lecture slides when I came across the formula in the 17th slide. The professor gave an explanation of the formula in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmZ_MOQ-XwA) lecture at around 1:10:00 timestamp. However, I did not understand the concept clearly.

**EDIT**

I have tried to explain the expression in the following way with the help of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model).

A stub of node $i$ can be connected to $2m-1$ other stubs.
The probability of a stub of node $i$ being connected to one of $k_j$ stubs is: $$\frac{k_j}{2m-1}$$ The probability that $k_i$ stubs being connected to one of $k_j$ stubs is:

$$
\frac{\overbrace{k_j+\ldots+k_j}^{k_i-times}}{2m-1} = 
\frac{k_ik_j}{2m-1}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reflections. Just from my understanding here the degrees of the nodes are fixed and connected means "adjacent".

From the video let's call $S_i$ the stubs of $i$ and $S_j$ the stubs of $j$.

Now I guess one should make the approximation:

$P(i, j \ \text{connected}) \sim \sum_{s\in S_i}P(i, j \ \text{connected via stub } s)$

I think this is an approximation because the events are not disjoints. Two nodes may be connected via multiple stubs therefore the probabilities do not simply add. Now we consider that:

$P(i, j \ \text{connected via stub } s)=\frac{k_j}{\text{Total number of stubs -1}}$

( where $-1$ is there because we cannot connect a stub to itself ). Of course $\text{"Total number of stubs $-1$"}=2m-1$.

Putting everything together, and replacing $\sum_{s\in S_i} \rightarrow k_i$, we get at least the formula you proposed.

Comment: Hi, see the edit portion in my question. Let me know if you agree on that.

Comment: before reading your link, I think you should say if you agree on what I wrote and if you think it is different from what you wrote ;)

Comment: What you wrote is basically the same as what I wrote except the approximation part. Node i has k_i stubs means node i has k_i half links say k_i1, k_i2...k_iki etc. The same can be imagined for node j. Now, k_i1 can be connected to node j in k_j ways via k_j1, k_j2,....k_jkj. Same can happen for k_i2...k_iki etc. Each possible connection is an event, right? So k_i1 connets with k_j1 is an event. k_i1 connects with k_j2 is another event. Then why ain't they disjoint events?

Comment: Two events are disjoints if they cannot happen simultaneously, and as a consequence the probability of the union is the sum of the probabilities. Actually it depends on how you define your events. But fix a,b two stubs in i and c,d two stubs in j. Than it can happen that a->c so that i, j are connected via this "event" and that c->d as well. These events can therefore happen at the same time and are therefore not disjoints in my opinion.

Comment: I think you are right. a->c and c->d both can happen simultaneously because the graph under consideration is a multigraph, so they are not disjoint events. In case of simple graph it's either a->c or c->d, but not simultaneously. So they are disjoint event. I'm satisfied with your explanation now.

Comment: Why would connected mean adjacent? Why wouldn't adjacent mean adjacent and connected mean connected? Vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected if there is a path from $u$ to $v$; they are adjacent if they are connected by a path of length one.

Answer (score 1):

To add some more details to the existing answer: the formula $\frac{k_i k_j}{2m - 1}$ given describes the *expected* number of edges between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$: for each half-stub of vertex $i$, the probability of being connected to vertex $j$ is $\frac{k_j}{2m-1}$, and by linearity of expectation (i.e. summing over the half-stubs of vertex $i$), we obtain $\frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$.

Thus, this in fact is an upper bound for the probability that $i$ and $j$ are connected, since $p_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(i \sim j) = \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{Edges}(i, j) \geq 1) \leq \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Edges}(i, j)] = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m - 1}$ by Markov's inequality.

Now in practice, this formula is probably true asymptotically, i.e. $p_{ij} = (1 + o(1)) \frac{k_i k_j}{2m - 1}$ (where we must make sense of what $n \to \infty$ means for the degree sequence). This is discussed more precisely in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532252/probability-that-2-nodes-are-connected-in-a-random-large-network).